# which one is the official command line package of pacemaker? crmsh or pcs?

Tags: cluster-computing, high-availability, pacemaker

I am working on a Linux-HA cluster with `pacemaker-1.1.10-1.el6_4.4`, as you know, in this pacemaker version, cluster command line functionality is not packaged with pacemaker package, I found 2 packages: `crmsh` and `pcs`, my question is which one is the official command line interface? which one is the recommendation? and what is the relation between them?

thanks,
Emre

Answer (score 6):

There is no One-True-CLI for Pacemaker.

The best suggestion is to use whatever your distribution provides support for (pcs on RHEL and its clones, crmsh for SLES).

The biggest difference is that pcs can configure the entire cluster (including corosync), not just the pacemaker portion.  It also doesn't try to have a 1-1 mapping between the underlying XML constructs and its command-line, which provides a certain degree of freedom to simplify things.

While there is no official relationship between the two projects, they continue to share ideas for improvements in a usability arms race :-)

Comment: Thanks for answer this, so do you mean **crmsh** is the 1-1 mapping between cib.xml construct and its command-line, is my understanding right?

Comment: For the most part, the crmsh syntax is the xml minus the tags and attribute names, sometimes reordered. However the specific problem I was referring to is that when parsing the xml produced by a command, the parser needs to produce the original command again.  This can be problematic if you want to allow shortcuts for producing common arrangements of resources/constraints, since crmsh doesn't have enough information to know which form produced the xml and it wont be clear to the user why the form they used wasn't preserved.